# How can I calculate aggregate values using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I need to calculate some aggregate values on a sql table in my rails project.
I've seen the various methods available in `ActiveRecord::Calculations`, but I can't manage to use anything but the built-in methods.

`MyModel.calculate(:stdev, 'value')` throws an exception `Undefined method 'stdev' for #<Arel::Attributes::Attribute`.

I understand from the code in `calculations.rb` that it calls at some point `column.send(operation)`, which cause the error, and I discover in `Arel::Expressions` that it can't handle anything but min, max, sum, average and count... So, it looks like I won't be able to use that.

So, my question becomes the following : Can I use the standard `select` method to get what I want, and get several aggregates at the same time ? How can I get the results, or set aliases for the resulting columns ?
I was thinking about using something like that :

```
MyModel.select("stdev(value)","average(value)")
```

Any way, any advice ? Or any nice trick for Arel to do my calculations ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: doesn't this work to set the alias: `MyModel.select("stdev(value) AS val1, average(value) AS val2")`

Comment: Yes, it does, but I was wondering if there was a "nicer" (more Arel/ActiveRecord like) way.

Comment: AR may filter out any other aggregate methods due to discrepancies between database syntax, or for security reasons. I think leonardoborges' syntax is as nice as it gets without getting over-engineered.